# How to split an entire sentence into characters in java?

Tags: java

I need to split:- "Hello World" into the following:

```
H

e

l

l

o

W

o

r

l

d
```

I have tried using .split(""). But after the space it is not working. How to split both strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use StringName.toCharArray()

hope this might help you.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want the spaces, remove them before you split. And don't use split to get characters, better to get a character array directly:

```
s.replaceAll(" ", "").toCharArray()
```

If you don't even need a character array and you just want to print, then it's better to use streaming with a filter:

```
s.chars().filter(c -> c != ' ').forEach(c -> System.out.println((char)c))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Hope it works:

```
    String str = "Hello World";
    char [] ch = str.toCharArray();

    for( int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++ ) {
        if( ch[i] != ' ' ) { 
            System.out.println( ch[i] );
       }
    }
```

Comment: There's no need to get the `char[]` here - it makes a copy of the array, which isn't necessary here. You can simply use `str.length()` and `str.charAt(i)`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I cannot print the character using foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.toCharArry` to convert a string into an array of characters:

```
String str = "Hello World";
char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want chars without space you can do the following

```
"Hello world".chars()
            .filter(e -> e != ' ')
            .forEach(e -> System.out.println((char)e));
```

Comment: That will also output the space (which seems to have been omitted in the example)